# Numerous dependencies don't get installed with "drush en -y" command for rooms module

Tags: drush

I tried to install the rooms module, obviously a very complex module with lots of dependencies, I tried with drush:

```
drush en rooms -y
```

This is the module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms

But even after doing that, from the back end, tons of dependencies are missing.

Additionally, the Rooms page has absolutely no information on required dependencies...

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Drush will only check the .info file for dependencies, in the case of the Rooms module those are:

```
dependencies[] = date
dependencies[] = date_api
dependencies[] = date_popup
dependencies[] = jquery_update
dependencies[] = libraries (>=2.x)
dependencies[] = variable
```

If Drush is missing any of those out, you have a buggy version of Drush and need to get an issue opened for it (or check for a similar existing one).

Other than that any "missing" dependencies are either down to a bug in the Rooms module, or your expectations being incorrect.

For example, maybe you're expecting Drush to auto-download all of the dependencies for the sub-modules included with Rooms as well?

It won't, those are considered separate modules. If you want those dependencies downloaded/installed automatically, you'll need to run `drush en` for each module individually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the implementation of the dependency-resolution feature is incomplete.  Note that dependencies in an info file are *modules*, and Drush download requests *projects*. It is easy to get a list of modules that a given project contains; however, there is no way to tell what project a given module is contained in, because this information simply is not maintained on drupal.org. So, at the current time, `drush en` will only fetch those dependencies where the module name equals the project name.

There have been some 3rd-party efforts to build a mapping from the module name to the project name, but so far, no one has attempted to implement this feature in Drush. The best way to get the required dependencies for a complex module is to find a distribution for it, such as [drupalrooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalrooms). Some distributions work better than others; I have not tried this one myself.

Comment: I'm sure that's all true (when has Greg been wrong? :P), but I'm not sure how it applies here - date contains date_api and date_popup, so that's satisfied by just downloading date, and the others are all projects in their own right. I'm not sure how that adds up to missing dependencies after an `en`?

Comment: Dependencies can have dependencies. I did not try to track down the dependency tree for the rooms module; just went with Occam's razor here.

Answer (score 0):

Rooms' dependencies are documented here: http://docs.roomify.us/rooms/requirements.html#rooms-requirements (You can find this by following the standard Documentation link on https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms)

Additionally there are detailed installation instructions here: http://docs.roomify.us/rooms/installation.html

hope this helps.